# What is the best way to update firebase database?

Tags: php, swift, database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am wondering if somebody could give me some advice regarding a firebase database.

I am going to create a firebase database, where I want to store around 1000 to 1500 events. 
I am going to be running a script which will retrieve these 1000 to 1500 events from multiple API's, every hour. Every event also has a score which can be different from the hour.

But here's my problem: I am doubting if I should loop through all the events and check if the score variable is different from the older one and update it accordingly. 
Or that it' more efficient/faster to clear the database everyhour and than add all events again?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: if you delete the event everyhour, then maybe a user at that time wants to check an event and he didnt see any event...

Comment: Why are you doing this? Firebase is a live database and if a node it added, edited or removed your apps will be notified of that. Polling may not be the best solution but without understanding the use case, this is going to be hard to answer.

Comment: I am creating an interactive event app, so the users can add events them self and I also add and update third party events through my api. And in the app people can vote for the events in realtime. So it’s also a possibility to have the 3rd party events separated from the ones in app, and just store those events in a seperate database. But I still can’t figure out which would be the best choice